# How to get count of intermediate vertices?

Tags: gremlin

Let's say there is a tree-like structure.

Top level: Warehouse

Next level: Storage space

Last level: Stored item

I want to get count of Storage spaces and Storage items per each warehouse.

I've already tried to get the number of Stored items: it's done pretty easily  using groupCount.

```
g.V().
      hasLabel('Warehouse').
      as('w').
      out('HAS_SPACE').
      hasLabel('Space').
      as('s').
      out('HAS_ITEM').
      hasLabel('Item').
      groupCount().by(select('w')).
      unfold().
      order().by(values, desc).
      limit(100).
      project('WarehouseName', 'ItemsCount').
          by(select(keys).values('Name')).
          by(select(values))
```

However I want to get count of 's' as well and I can't think of any fast way to achieve it. I've thought about counting traversals something like:

```
g.V().
      hasLabel('Warehouse').
      project('WarehouseName', 'SpaceCount', 'ItemCount').
          by('Name').
          by(out('HAS_SPACE').count()).
          by(out('HAS_SPACE').out('HAS_ITEMS').count())
```

but it works extremely slow on large number of vertices (there are about 26M).

Is there any other way to get that count?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `groupCount` as `sideEffect` by giving it a name:

```
g.V().hasLabel('Warehouse').as('w')
  .out('HAS_SPACE').hasLabel('Space').as('s')
  .groupCount('spaceCount').by(select('w'))
  .out('HAS_ITEM').hasLabel('Item')
  .groupCount('itemsCount').by(select('w'))
  .count().select('spaceCount', 'itemsCount')
```

Note that this will return 2 maps, one for spaces and one for items.
If you need to get it as a single map you can replace last line with:

```
.count().union(select('spaceCount'),select('itemsCount')).unfold()
.group().by(keys).by(select(values).fold()).unfold()
```

The result will be a map of arrays, of which first value is spaces count and second is items count.